Build getting failed with jdk 17 for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:3.1.10
Gradle 7.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2024-02-05 14:29:18 UTC
Revision:     e0bb3fc8cefad8432c9033cdfb12dc14facc9dd9

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17 (Oracle Corporation 17+35-LTS-2724)
OS:           Linux 5.4.17-2136.308.9.el8uek.x86_64 amd64


I am trying to build from source for the org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:3.1.10 and I am getting the below error ->
[root@65ec4d6d4c34 spring-boot]# ./gradlew build

> Task :buildSrc:test

OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests > optionalDependenciesAreAddedToMainSourceSetsRuntimeClasspath() FAILED
    org.gradle.testkit.runner.UnexpectedBuildFailure at OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests.java:107

OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests > optionalDependenciesAreAddedToTestSourceSetsRuntimeClasspath() FAILED
    org.gradle.testkit.runner.UnexpectedBuildFailure at OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests.java:107

OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests > optionalDependenciesAreAddedToMainSourceSetsCompileClasspath() FAILED
    org.gradle.testkit.runner.UnexpectedBuildFailure at OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests.java:107

OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests > optionalDependenciesAreAddedToTestSourceSetsCompileClasspath() FAILED
    org.gradle.testkit.runner.UnexpectedBuildFailure at OptionalDependenciesPluginIntegrationTests.java:107

TestFailuresPluginIntegrationTests > multiProjectParallel() FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at TestFailuresPluginIntegrationTests.java:103

TestFailuresPluginIntegrationTests > multiProjectContinue() FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at TestFailuresPluginIntegrationTests.java:87



Please advise on what might be the issue.
I am not sure how to debug it.
